# SugarCRM Get an effective TimeDate from a SugarBean field

Tags: datetime, sugarcrm, sugarbean

I must be missing something obvious, but it seems that I'm unable to find a way to get the TimeDate object from the value of a SugarBean field.

Let's say I get a specific Lead with this kind of call:

```
$lead = BeanFactory::retrieveBean('Leads', "18bfc69e-8cd4-11e7-ad08-000c29b1a36e");
```

then any call to this:

```
$lead->date_entered
```

will return a string value: `"2017-08-29 16:05"` (note the absence of seconds).

So then, for example, if I try to use such value to create a SugarTimeDate:

```
$TimeDate = new TimeDate();
$SugarTimeDate = $TimeDate->fromDb($lead->date_entered);
```

it will return false, since the value provided to `fromDb()` is not in the proper format (the seconds are missing).

When looking at the SQL table with Toad, I can see that the information is effectively stored in the database as a DateTime, with the value `08/29/2017 16:05:56`. But the SugarBean object provides it as a text with a format that is incomplete.

So how can you get the effective SugarTimeDate, TimeDate or DateTime from a Field in a given SugarBean, ideally as an object?

I searched, and all the example I found was about creating a new date object from Now to set to a field in a SugarBean, but none to set a datetime field from an existing datetime field.

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it's not entirely clear what you're expecting with an "effective TimeDate". Sounds like you're expecting it to be an object of some sort, but what's the end result? It's also not clear with SugarCRM version you're using.

Comment: Also, is the problem that you require the seconds? Or just that you can't create an object from said date?

Comment: I was looking for a way to do a round-trip on a datevalue, getting a date and reset it in another place, but by using $bean->field, you loose a piece of the information, which is an issue if you use these dates to do some sync process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By playing around, and with some help from [Patrick McQueen](https://community.sugarcrm.com/message/98222-re-get-an-effective-timedate-from-a-sugarbean-field), it appears there 2 ways to get the effective date value of a field.

First solution I found was to do a SugarQuery with a select on the needed fields, which then returns the full date information, so `"2017-08-29 16:05:56"`. A bit overkill, but it does the job.

The other solution brought up by Patrick is to use the `fetcher_row` array from the bean object, which will return the full date information also. So:

```
$lead->fetched_row['date_entered']
```

will returns also `"2017-08-29 16:05:56"`.

So in any case an effective date is required ("round-trip" with a get then a set, or some sync requirement), the `fetched_row[]` is the solution, and the "direct" call to the field `$bean->field` is to be definitely avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't 100% clear what you were trying to accomplish (see my comments), but I'm guessing that you want the fromUser() function instead, i.e.

```
$SugarTimeDate = $TimeDate->fromUser($lead->date_entered);
```

The reason why, is that Sugar prepares the data for the GUI (including formatting the date as per user preferences) at the point your code is being called. This includes stripping out the seconds. Doing the above fromUser() function will return a SugarDateTime object based on the *current user's configured date format* with a full date string as a "date" property. This, in turn, could be dealt with elsewhere by using this standard format.

Comment: Thanks Reisclef.Note that if you do this, then you will loose a part of the information (the seconds) since the $lead->date_entered doesn't return the effective value of the field. I tried and the value int he SugarTimeDate is then:  "2017-08-29 12:05:00.000000"

Comment: Yes, that is very true. You didn't really state that you needed the seconds, or what it was for, so I was just providing the answer to what you asked.